# Recursive Backtracking C++, Memory address changing, damaging pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, vector, pass-by-reference

I am currently working on a recursive backtracking method for maze generation. At the moment I am struggling to get the correct values from the `GetNeighbours()` function. Within the function, it returns the correct coordinates, however, when referencing them in another function `RecursiveBacktracking()`, the points are no longer valid and contain incorrect values.

I've been trying to debug this for quite a while and just can't seem to figure it out.

Any explanation as to why this is would be incredibly helpful!

Thaks

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <stack>

class Node{
    public:
        std::vector<Node*> GetNeighbours(Node* baseNode, std::vector<std::vector<Node>> mazeVector){
                
                std::vector<Node*> neighbours;
                //Get south neighbour
                if(baseNode->ypos + 1 < mazeVector.size()){

                    if(!mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos+1).at(baseNode->xpos).isVisited){
                        neighbours.push_back(&mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos+1).at(baseNode->xpos));
                    }
                }
                //Get north neighbour
                if(baseNode->ypos - 1 >= 0){

                    if(!mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos-1).at(baseNode->xpos).isVisited){
                        neighbours.push_back(&mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos-1).at(baseNode->xpos));
                       // std::cout << neighbours[0]->ypos << ", " << neighbours[0]->xpos;
                    }
                }
                //Get east neighbour
                if(baseNode->xpos + 1 < mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).size()){

                    if(!mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).at(baseNode->xpos+1).isVisited){
                        neighbours.push_back(&mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).at(baseNode->xpos+1));
                       // std::cout << neighbours[0]->ypos << ", " << neighbours[0]->xpos;
                    }
                }
                if(baseNode->xpos -1 >= 0){

                    if(!mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).at(baseNode->xpos-1).isVisited){
                        neighbours.push_back(&mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).at(baseNode->xpos-1));
                        //std::cout << neighbours[0]->ypos << ", " << neighbours[0]->xpos;
                    }
                }

                std::random_device rd;
                std::mt19937 g(rd());

                std::shuffle(neighbours.begin(), neighbours.end(), g);

                // for(int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++){
                //     std::cout << "Neighbours[" << i << "] before return = (" << neighbours[i]->ypos << ", " << neighbours[i]->xpos << ")" << std::endl;
                //     std::cout << "Memory Address [" << i << "] within function = " << neighbours[i] << std::endl;
                //     std::cout << "Memory Address [" << i << "]within maze = " << &mazeVector[neighbours[i]->ypos][neighbours[i]->xpos] << std::endl;
                // }
                return neighbours;

            }

        bool isVisited = false;
        int ypos;
        int xpos;
      /*  Node(int y, int x, bool visited = false){
            this->ypos = y;
            this-> xpos = x;
            this-> isVisited = visited;
        }
        */


        
};
void PrintMaze(std::vector<std::vector<Node>>& mazeVector){
    for(int i = 0; i < mazeVector.size(); i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeVector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            Node* currentNode = &mazeVector.at(i).at(j);
            if(currentNode->isVisited){
                std::cout << 'X';
            }else{
                std::cout << '.';
            }
           // std::cout << &currentNode <<" = (" << currentNode->ypos << ", " << currentNode->xpos <<")";
            
           // std::cout << currentNode.GetNeighbours(currentNode, i, j, mazeVector).size();
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        
    }

} 

void RecursiveBacktracking(std::vector<std::vector<Node>>& maze, int x, int y){
    _sleep(500);
    std::cout<<"------GENERATING------" << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<Node*> stack;
    stack.emplace_back(&maze[0][0]);
    Node* currentNode = stack[0];
    currentNode->isVisited = true;
    while(stack.size() > 0){
        _sleep(3000);
        PrintMaze(maze);
        
        currentNode->isVisited = true;
        std::vector<Node*> neighbours = currentNode->GetNeighbours(currentNode, maze);
        PrintMaze(maze);
        // for(int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++){
        //             std::cout << "Neighbours[" << i << "] after return = (" << neighbours[i]->ypos << ", " << neighbours[i]->xpos  << ")" << std::endl;
        //             std::cout << "Neighbours[" << i << "] Memory after return = (" << neighbours[i] << std::endl;
        //         }
        if(neighbours.size() > 0){
            stack.emplace_back(neighbours[0]);
            std::cout << "Selected neighbour = (" <<  stack[stack.size()-1]->ypos << ", " << stack[stack.size()-1]->xpos << ")" << std::endl;
            //std::cout<< "Selected Neighbour Coords: " << currentNode-> ypos<< ", " << currentNode-> xpos<< std::endl;
            currentNode = stack[stack.size()-1];
        }else{
           
            stack.pop_back();
            currentNode = stack[stack.size()-1];

        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++)
        {
           
            /* code */
        }
        
         std::cout<< "Size while in loop: "<<stack.size() << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout<<stack.size() << std::endl;

}


int main(){
    int length;
    int width;
    std::cout << "Please enter and length and width: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> length >> width;
    std::cout << "Please enter a seed for maze generation or enter '0' for a random seed: " << std::endl;
    int seed;
    std::cin >> seed;
    if(seed == 0){
        std::srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    }else{
    std::srand(seed);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<Node>> mazeVector(length, std::vector<Node>(width));

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            Node currentNode;/* = Node(i, j); */
            currentNode.ypos = i;
            currentNode.xpos = j;
            mazeVector.at(i).at(j) = currentNode;
        }
    }

   PrintMaze(mazeVector);
   RecursiveBacktracking(mazeVector, 0, 0);

   



return 1; 
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<Node>> mazeVector` -- Are you aware you are passing this by value, meaning that the function is working on a local copy?  What happens to that copy when the function returns?

Comment: Scale back your code, possibly all the way to an empty `main` function. Add one or two lines, build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors, and when it builds test the code. If it works then add another one or two lines. And so on. It will make it much easier to debug code that causes problems, to isolate it into a [mre], and to solve problems.

Comment: Passing vectors by value is a tell-tale sign that you are a C# or Java programmer who has gotten tripped up by how C++ works with respect to passing parameters.  When you pass by value in C++, a *copy* is made in the function, and when that function exits, that copy goes away.  C#, Java, and other languages do not work this way in that the actual vector is being passed and used.  In C++, to pass by reference, you must explicitly state it by using `&`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie haha read me like a book! All I needed was the extra & and it started working again after minor tweaks!

Answer (score 3):

This is being passed by value, meaning that `mazeVector` is a local copy.

`std::vector<std::vector<Node>> mazeVector`

Then in the function itself, you are doing this:

`neighbours.push_back(&mazeVector.at(baseNode->ypos).at(baseNode->xpos+1));`

You are storing the address of a temporary inside of `neighbors`, and then eventually returning `neighbors`.  When the function returns,

`return neighbours;`

that `mazeVector` will be destroyed, thus all of those addresses are no longer valid.

You should pass the `mazeVector` by reference, not by value:

`std::vector<Node*> GetNeighbours(Node* baseNode, std::vector<std::vector<Node>>& mazeVector)`

But even with this, there is no guarantee of your code working.  The reason is that you should not be storing addresses of vector elements.  What if the vector is resized beyond the capacity, thus having to reallocate the internal vector memory?  All of those pointers you stored will now be invalidated.

Comment: Changed the wording.